# SQL Calculations With Multi-Group Affiliations

Tags: sql, sql-view, sql-function

I'm attempting to have a function or view that is able to calculate and roll up various counts while being able to search on a many to many affiliation.

Here is an example data set:

```
Invoice Table:
InvoiceID LocationID   StatusID
1         5            1
2         5            1
3         5            1
4         5            2
5         7            2
5         7            1
5         7            2

Group Table:
GroupID   GroupName
1         Group 1
2         Group 2

GroupToLocation Table:
GroupToLocationID GroupID  LocationID
1                 1        5
2                 2        5
3                 2        7
```

I have gotten to the point where I could sum up the various statuses per location and get this:

```
 LocationID     Status1   Status2
 5              3         1
 7              1         2
```

Location 5 has 3 Invoices with a status of 1, and 1 invoice with a status of 2 while Location 7 has 1 status 1 and 2 status 2

There are two groups, and Location 5 is in both, while Location 7 is only in the second. I need to be able to set it up where I can append a where statement like this:

```
select * from vw_GroupCounts
where GroupName = 'Group 2'
```

or

```
select Invoice, SUM(*) from vw_GroupCounts
where GroupName = 'Group 2'
```

And that result in only getting Location 7. Whenever I do this, as I have to use left joins or something along those lines, the counts are duplicating for each group the the Location is affiliated with. I know I could do something along the lines of a subquery and pass in the GroupName into that, but the system I am working with uses a dynamic query builder that appends WHERE statements based on user input.

I don't mind using view, or functions, or any number of functions inside of functions, but I hope there is a way to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since locations 5 and 7 are in Group 2, if you search for group 2 in the where clause after joining all the tables, then you would get all records in this case, this isn't duplication, just the way the data is. A different join wouldn't change this, only changing the data. Let me know if I am misunderstanding something though.

Here is how you would join them to do that search.

[image]

Here it is with your first example of the location and status count.

[image]

Comment: What does the Count turn out to be for number of invoices at Location 5 if you don't add a where clause? My understanding is that it would count up all the records twice, once for each group. If Location 5 was then added to a third group, it would would count up each record three times.  That's what been happening here.

Comment: Yes the count would double for location 5, and you would get 11 rows total in that case because location 5 appears 4 times in the invoice table, and 2 times in the GroupToLocation table, and they would multiply against each other for 8 rows, plus 3 for location 7. However, if you are always searching for a single group in the where clause this would not happen. If you remove the where clause and are not searching for a group at all, then you have no reason to join to the group to location table.

Comment: It would only be wrong if you needed to join to it to search for more than one group. If this is the case, then I would say the data is structured wrong, you should just add a group column to the invoice table. If an invoice can only ever be in one group at a time, then this is the proper solution.

Comment: Yeah, we're using the dynamic builder that utilizes a function that isn't going to not join things without a where clause. I came up with a solution though: divide by the count of groups it is attached to (and if none, divide by 1). That seems to be giving accurate counts.